# Is there any way to set Setter property of BsonMemberMap? (C# mongo driver)

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there any way to specify Setter for BsonMongoMap?
`map.GetMemberMap("Items").Setter`

I haven't found any way to do this. But, I hope I can override this Setter somehow